# Sample of the array after a recursive function

Tags: arrays, recursion

After some recursive function I have an array:

**first iteration:**
Array ( [category_id] => 3 [title] => Aqua [parent] => 0 ) )

**second:**
Array ( [category_id] => 5 [title] => Sea aqua [parent] => 3 ) Array ( [category_id] => 3 [title] => Aqua [parent] => 0 ) )

and so on...

How can I show only one array where [parent] => 0  ?

Comment: your question is not clear: if you have 3 arrays that answer your requirement, which one of them will you "show" ?

Comment: I`ll show where [parent] => 0. I need to get the top level category_id and in my case it will be when parent = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($arrays as $arr){
  if ($arr['parent'] == 0){
     echo $arr['category_id'] . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! It`s realy help me to solve the problem:) Just find out where I made mistake.